# MSVC generates strange/slow binary for some multiplications and divisions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I use MSVC 2010 SP1 and I have the following line of C++ code:

```
int32_t c = (int64_t(a)*int64_t(b))>>2;
```

When `a` and `b` are not constants, MSVC correctly generates a 32 bit `imul` and `shrd` instructions. But when `a` or `b` are constants it generates a call to `_allmull` instead of the `imul` instruction. Could there be any reason for this? How can I force/guide it to always generate good code? The thing that bothers me is why it generates worse code when it has more compile time information. I have found that `_allmull` function performs 64 bit multiplication, but I think it is not needed in this case.

I have also noticed that for a line `int32_t c = (int64_t(a)*int64_t(b))/4;` it even generates _alldiv for the division by 4.

**Edit:**
It seems to be a compiler error. I have filled a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657680/slow-assembly-for-some-multiplications-in-c#details).

Comment: Why're you using int64_t if you know it's not needed?

Comment: Semantics of signed and unsigned integers differ. What if you use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`?

Comment: @Erik: On Intel compatible processors (and probably most others) imul with two 32b arguments generates 64b result. And I only need to shift this result before it is assigned to a 32 bit variable. No 64 bit multiplication is needed.

Comment: @Alexandre C. : For unsigned values the generated assembly is correct in all three mentioned cases. But I need it to work for signed values. Any tips?

Comment: @Juraj: no, sorry. I suspected this problem, but I'm not an expert in this area. At least you know where your problem is.

Comment: You should provide a more complete section of code with your bug report.  MS will take any and every opportunity to close bugs on Connect, and not providing compilable code or the compiler options you used will make that even more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially related: if you want to be sure to exploit the `imul` capability of performing 32x32=>64 bit multiplication, you can use the [`Int32x32To64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383703%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "fake API" (actually a macro):

> Multiplies two signed 32-bit integers, returning a signed 64-bit integer result. The function performs optimally on 32-bit Windows.
>
> This function is implemented on all platforms by optimal inline code: a single multiply instruction that returns a 64-bit result.

By the way, did you enable the optimizations? I would be quite baffled if, with optimizations enabled, the compiler wasn't able to figure it out by itself.

---

***Edit***:

interestingly enough, looking for `Int32x32To64` in `winnt.h`, you find, for x86:

```
//
// The x86 C compiler understands inline assembler. Therefore, inline functions
// that employ inline assembler are used for shifts of 0..31.  The multiplies
// rely on the compiler recognizing the cast of the multiplicand to int64 to
// generate the optimal code inline.
//

#define Int32x32To64( a, b ) (LONGLONG)((LONGLONG)(LONG)(a) * (LONG)(b))
#define UInt32x32To64( a, b ) (ULONGLONG)((ULONGLONG)(DWORD)(a) * (DWORD)(b))
```

So, it should definitely produce `imul` if even the Platform SDK trusts the compiler to do the right thing.

---

***Edit again***:

If you need to be sure to get an `imul`, you could use the [`__emul` compiler intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2s81xt0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: That macro does not seem to work in my case either. Without the `>>` operation it works nicely. But the shift is somehow misleading the compiler to generate `call _allmul`

Comment: @Juraj: what about the `__emul` intrinsic?

Comment: I have just tried the `__emul` thing and it seems to work. I don't like it much because it is very compiler specific and non-portable, but I could live with it as a workaround when MSVC is used. Thanks.

Comment: @Juraj: I too do not like compiler-specific stuff, but I don't see many other choices; on the other hand, it would be interesting to benchmark the code generated with and without the intrinsic, it would be a nice surprise if it turned out that the compiler is actually knowing what it is doing, and the seemingly slower code in that case is actually faster.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Compiler seems to be wrong here. According to a quick test the _allmull version is 2-times slower. If I use division by 4 instead of `>>2`, the compiler generates `_alldiv` and the code is 10-times slower than it could be with `__emul` and `>>`.

Comment: @Juraj: well, maybe there's material for a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I see the allmul if I run the compiler without optimisation, but with /Ox, I see a combination of shifts and adds that's dependent on the value of the constant part.

I think you need to provide a specific bit of code, and the compiler options you've used.

Comment: Have you tried some larger non-power-of-two constant (for example 150)? For small constants it seems to do some extra optimizations. I have the optimizations turned on (/Ox).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as a workaround:

```
int32_t c = (int64_t(int32_t(a))*int64_t(int32_t(b)))>>2;
```

Comment: Yes, and it does not seem to help. It is equivalent to the Int32x32To64() suggested by Matteo Italia.

Comment: Hey!  Good to meet ya at the SO Meetup!